# Number of bijections from a finite set to itself

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

We claim that a set $A$ with $n$ elements has $n!$ bijections from $A$ to itself.

Let $A = \{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ be a set. We will show that there are $n!$ bijections from $A$ to itself.
For $a_1,$ we can map it to any of $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ which gives us $n$ choices for the image of $a_1$. Suppose, without loss of generality, $a_1$ is mapped to $a_n$. Now, we consider $a_2$, which can be mapped to any of $a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1}$ owing to the fact that the map is injective. This gives us $n-1$ choices.

Continuing in this fashion, we have that the number of choices keeps decreasing by 1 and as $A$ is a finite set, this process must terminate. We have
$$n(n-1)(n-2)\dots(1) = n!$$
choices in total. These are the number of bijective maps and we are done.

While I think that my argument is correct, I am not sure whether my proof is rigorous or complete. Please see if this is correct and suggest a better way to write the same.

Comment: Your proof is fine.

Comment: Your argument is correct but I wouldn't say "without loss of generality" we can map $a_1$ to $a_n$.  We are *counting* *all* the bijections and when we restrict it to $a_n$ we are no longer counting all of them.  It' be more accurate to say "We may map $a_1$ to any of the $a_m$ values.   Whichever one we  map to there we will have $m-1$ remaining values to choose what we map $a_2$ to".

Comment: Alternatively you can say.  "let's consider all the values of $a_1,....,a_n$ of which $a_1$ is *not* mapped to.  There are $n-1$ such remaining values. Let reindex them as $b_1,..., b_{m-1}$. Now, we consider $a_2$ and it can be mapped to any of $b_1,...., b_{n-1}$ owing......"

Comment: Thank you for your comments. We can map $a_1$ to $n$ possible elements. Then, for $a_2$, we can map it to $n-1$ possible elements, and continuing in this fashion, the number of possible elements keeps decreasing by 1. As $A$ is finite, this process must terminate at some point, giving us the number of possibilities by the product principle. Is this a better argument?